# How can I design a map viewer web application with GIF map images? (AVL TRACKING SYSTEM)

Tags: c#, java

I am a student and my final project in graduate study of Computer engineering is design and development a map viewer web application that must be used for an AVL tracking system.
I am trying with applet in java.

First, map images format are GIF/JPG with  big/large amount size(100MB).
Now, I want to find, how I break map images into smaller size and is true if I tiling images in order to showing on viewer, and how?

I program a coordinating application to convert lat/lng to pixels and vice versa,
Now I must to find what to doing with maps and find a method  that is recommended to showing images of map in viewer.

If you have any idea to tiling or know about it.. or you recommend another method  please help me
thanks

Comment: i want to write Map Application myself.
the main problem is now that: How i can tiling the image? 
for rendering tiles in given zoom level how i must request given tiles ( or all off tiles) to show in a window that holding 2*3 tiles( for example)?
in other word, given, the application render 6 tiles that user requested to find his/her car (AVL!!!), and user want to render another location and navigate map (like google map or another map viewer applications...) , in jav applet class i must create an array of tilesto cashing images,now ifyou have an idea to do this please help me.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a look at JAI for Java which has a class that implements tile based images. I have not used it much so i cannot get into specifics but what i know is that if you are looking for tile based images in Java JAI is the way to go.

So Google JAI and take it from there.

Answer (score -1):

i may be completly off-track, but since you got long/lat, why don't you use a google map ? with a simple javascript timer, you could have quiclky a near real-time display.

the only problem would be the license and/or daily limit (this may not be a problem if this is not a live/productive system).

regards,

Guillaume

Comment: I can assume why this was down voted (i think it has to do with the fact that the user who asked the question is supposed to write the app himself and not use something ready) but would the down voter supply a comment as to why he casted the negative vote? I think that helps us understand what we did wrong. I hate it when i have my answers down voted with no explenation

Comment: I stand by my reponse. Even more for a student : why replicate existing app, with probably less features. Instead, you can add functionalities (historical position data for a given vehicule for exemple, as a simplified path).